# How to read multiple integer values from one line in Java using BufferedReader object?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, buffer, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader class to read inputs in my Java program.
I want to read inputs from a user who can enter multiple integer data in single line with space.
I want to read all these data in an integer array.

Input format-
the user first enters how many numbers he/she want to enter

And then multiple integer values in the next single line-

INPUT:

5

2 456 43 21 12

Now, I read input using an object (br) of BufferedReader

```
int numberOfInputs = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Next, I want to read next line inputs in an array

```
int a[] = new int[n];
```

But we cannot read using this technique

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   a[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); //won't work
}
```

So, is there any solution to my problem or we can't just read multiple integers from one line using BufferedReader objects

Because using Scanner object we can read this type of input

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   a[i]=in.nextInt(); //will work..... 'in' is object of Scanner class
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the next:

```
int a[] = new int[n];
String line = br.readLine(); // to read multiple integers line
String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
}
```

Comment: @LalitChoudhary You're welcome. Do not forget that if an answer solves  your question satisfactorily, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/227183).

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party but you can do this in one liner in Java 8 using `streams`.

```
InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr);

int[] input = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to read integers and you didn't know number of integers

```
String[] integersInString = br.readLine().split(" ");
int a[] = new int[integersInString.length];
for (int i = 0; i < integersInString.length; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(integersInString[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())` -> Reads a whole line and then converts it to Integers.

`scanner.nextInt()` -> Reads every single token one by one within a single line then tries to convert it to integer.

```
String[] in = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+"); 
// above code reads the whole line, trims the extra spaces 
// before or after each element until one space left, 
// splits each token according to the space and store each token as an element of the string array.


for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(in[i]);

// Converts each element in the string array as an integer and stores it in an integer array.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int i;
        System.out.println("enter the array element");
        InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader();
        BufferedReader ib= new BufferedReader(isr);
        int a[]=new int [5];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            a[i]= Integer.parseInt(ib.readLine(a[i]));

        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. The answer should be useful to a broader public, not just to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for List:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Stream.of(reader.readLine().split("\\s+")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And it is almost the same for array:

```
int[] numbersArray = Arrays.stream(reader.readLine().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer class of java.util package. The StringTokenizer class allows an application to break a string into tokens. You can use this tokens using nextToken() method of StringTokenizer class.

You can use following constructor of StringTokenizer:

StringTokenizer(String str, String delimiter);

you can use space(" ") as delemeter.

```
int a[] = new int[N];
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine() , " ");
for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you mentioned there are two lines-
First line takes number of integers and second takes that many number

```
INPUT: 5 2 456 43 21 12
```

So to address this and covert it into array -

```
String[] strs = inputData.trim().split("\\s+");  //String with all inputs 5 2 456 43 21 12

int n= Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);    //As you said first string contains the length

int a[] = new int[n];               //Initializing array of that length

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)         
{

a[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i+1]);     // a[0] will be equal to a[1] and so on....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i/p:34 54

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                                                        
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()," ");
 for(int i=0;i<st.countTokens();i++){
   a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
   b=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
 }
```

//For fast input output for one line