# Processing A Math Formula

Tags: java

I would like to be able to make a program that uses the following formula :

```
z= 1/y (x)
```

I would like it to ask the following questions:

1. Enter the number of times that it has occured this year (this part I know how to do) (y)
2. How many times has it occured today (x)

The only thing I have so far is ......

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class javaCalculator 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        String operation;


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter the first number");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("please enter the second number");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter operation");
        operation = op.next();

        if (operation == "+");
        {
            System.out.println("your answer is" + (num1 + num2));
        }
        if  (operation == "-");
        {
            System.out.println("your answer is" + (num1 - num2));
        }

        if (operation == "/");
        {
            System.out.println("your answer is" + (num1 / num2));
        }
        if (operation == "*")
        {
            System.out.println("your answer is" + (num1 * num2));
        }


    }
}
```

can someone help??

Thank you! (i am in high shcool and would like to input a formula I made, but I also need to convert it into html..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read multiple integer values from one line in java using BufferedReader object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491997/how-to-read-multiple-integer-values-from-one-line-in-java-using-bufferedreader-o)

Comment: ... user got his/her answer and thereafter removed account....

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class ComputeXbyY
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            // Using Scanner for Getting Input from User
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter: y - ");
            int y = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You entered y "+y);

            System.out.println("Please enter: x - ");
            int x = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You entered x "+x);

            if(y!=0){
                float res = (float)x/(float)y;
                System.out.println("Result:  "+res);        
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I compile it everything is great! No errors! When I 'run' it what is the first thing that I would enter?

Comment: You enter Y first. Then X. I have updated the answer.
(Please play with the code a bit more. Write print statement more. See what happens.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now I am working on a code for html to make the 'calculator' part of it. I can credit you at the bottom of my calculator page. Thank you for your help!